# Simple Netty handler, iterate through message byte by byte

Tags: java, netty

Is there an example of a very barebones Netty handler which simply gets whatever data is sent on the wire and writes it to a file?

I was thinking of something along the lines of this:

```
public class SimpleHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        // get data from request and write to a file
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also just use this method to transfer the content of the ChannelBuffer to an OutputStream:

http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#readBytes(java.io.OutputStream,%20int)

So something like this:

```
public class FileWriterHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    private final String filename;

    public FileWriterHandler(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, MessageEvent event) throws Exception{
        ChannelBuffer buffer = (ChannelBuffer)event.getMessage();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename, true)
            buffer.readBytes(out, buffer.readableBytes());
        } finally {
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one of these for testing a while back:

```
public class FileWriterHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    private final String filename;

    public FileWriterHandler(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, MessageEvent event) {
        ChannelBuffer buffer = (ChannelBuffer)event.getMessage();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
        buffer.readBytes(bytes);
        try {
            DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename, true));
            stream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw runtime(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just for test hence i'm just re-throwing exceptions and not really dealing with them properly.  Hope that's helpful.

You would set this up as follows:

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = initializedSomehow();
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
        return pipeline(new FileWriterHandler("yourfile.txt"));
    }
});
```